# i want to send email on custom post field (job_status == 2) but it is not working

Tags: custom-field, email

```
add_action('updated_post_meta', 'send_email_on_job_complete',10,4);
function send_email_on_job_complete($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)
 {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if("jobs" !== $post_type) return;
    $job_status = types_get_field_meta_value("job-status-1",$post_id); 

    if($job_status == 1)
        {
            return;
        }    
    else
        {
            $user_id = get_post_meta($post_id,"user_id",true);
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            $user_full_name = $user_info->display_name;
            $user_email = $user_info->user_email;

            //sending email from user to admin
            $to_admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
            $subject_to_admin = 'JOB COMPLETED';
            $body_to_admin = 'Job is completed which is posted by '.$user_full_name.'.';
            $headers_to_admin = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

            //sending email from admin to user
            $subject_to_user = 'JOB COMPLETED';
            $body_to_user = 'Your posted job is complete plz give review about it.';
            $headers_to_user = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            wp_mail( $to_admin_email, $subject_to_admin, $body_to_admin, $headers_to_admin );
            wp_mail( $user_email, $subject_to_user, $body_to_user, $headers_to_user );
        } 
}
```

Comment: You want a mail to be sent every time a meta value is updated or when post is updated? Please add some description to your question.

Comment: First of all, make sure from the mail and `updated_post_meta` hook. You can check it in the first of line in your function. For example:
mail('youremail', 'Test', print_r($meta_id, 1));

Comment: I want to send mail when the meta value is updated. This function sends email continuously.

Comment: This hook runs for every meta value. What you can do is add a check for `$meta_key`. i.e. `if($meta_key != 'your_meta_key')return;`.

Comment: please explain this little more. How can i do this?

Comment: Please, [edit the question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/299651/edit) and explain the question, what you have done and the problem you have. Just dumping code makes you question really hard to guess what your exact problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is with reference to the comments to question.
Instead of running mail function on every meta value update, it needs to run on your specific meta.

You will also need to change your code accordingly.

First check for your `$meta_key` and then take value from `$meta_value`. Write you conditions on these fields and trigger mail accordingly.

```
add_action('updated_post_meta', 'send_email_on_job_complete',10,4);
function send_email_on_job_complete($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)
 {
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if("jobs" !== $post_type) return;

    if("job-status-1" !== $meta_key) return; //Check if currently updated meta key is meta key you want to check.Else return.

    $job_status = types_get_field_meta_value("job-status-1",$post_id); 

    if($job_status == 1)
        {
            return;
        }    
    else
        {
            $user_id = get_post_meta($post_id,"user_id",true);
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            $user_full_name = $user_info->display_name;
            $user_email = $user_info->user_email;

            //sending email from user to admin
            $to_admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
            $subject_to_admin = 'JOB COMPLETED';
            $body_to_admin = 'Job is completed which is posted by '.$user_full_name.'.';
            $headers_to_admin = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

            //sending email from admin to user
            $subject_to_user = 'JOB COMPLETED';
            $body_to_user = 'Your posted job is complete plz give review about it.';
            $headers_to_user = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            wp_mail( $to_admin_email, $subject_to_admin, $body_to_admin, $headers_to_admin );
            wp_mail( $user_email, $subject_to_user, $body_to_user, $headers_to_user );
        } 
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Please, add some explanation about what the code does and how it answers the question. Just dumping code is not considered a good answer.